# PyCharm Warning: Unexpected type for filter on dictionary

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following code in PyCharm:

```
LOCATIONS = {'loc1': [a, b, c], 'loc2': [d, e], 'loc3': [f, g]}
labels = ['loc2', 'loc3']
task_locations = dict(filter(lambda location: location[0] in labels, LOCATIONS.items()))
```

PyCharm issues the following warning on `filter(lambda location: location[0] in labels, LOCATIONS.items())`:

```
Unexpected type(s):
(Iterator[str])
Possible types:
(Mapping)
(Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]])
```

How should I act on the warning? The same expression, but on a `Dict[str, int]`, is without the warning. So I guess it has something to do with the `LOCATIONS` being a `Dict[str, List[str]]`.

Comment: That's clearly a bug in PyCharm. You should simply report that bug, so that they know about it, and can fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a false positive from PyCharm. It thinks that filter will return `Iterator[str]` which is not the case, as its input is `dict_items` which is an `Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]]`.

You can also simplify the code like this:

```
task_locations = {k: v for k, v in LOCATIONS.items() if k in labels}
```

and PyCharm doesn't complain in this case.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing. Moreover it allowed me to get the list of teams right away:
`teams_in_locations = [team for (location, teams) in LOCATIONS.items() if location in labels for team in teams]`

Answer (score 0):

I see Pycharm detect out put of filter(lambda location: location[0] in labels, LOCATIONS.items()) is Iterater[str]. 
But actually it is Iterable[tuple] so code running oke

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do this:

```
task_locations = dict(map(lambda item: (item[0], item[1]), filter(lambda location: location[0] in labels, LOCATIONS.items())))
```

no warning